# IP Office Phone Manager doesn't appear to work in Windows 10

Tags: tapi, avaya

I have used this software before in Windows 7 without any issue but since upgrading to Windows 10 it has stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

So this took a bit of research and after trying these steps the program started to work in Windows 10. Here are the steps you need to try.

- Remove the "PhoneManager.exe.manifest" file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Avaya\IP Office\Phone Manager".
- RUN and type

regedit and click ok

go to

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\BFE

Right click on it-permissions

Click on ADD and type

Everyone and click ok

Now Click on Everyone

Below you have permission for users

Select full control and click ok

Now,open RUN and type

services.msc and click ok

start base filtering engine service and then windows firewall service

- In Registry Editor, browse to the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess
  Right click SharedAccess, and click Permissions.
  Click Add.
  In the “Enter the object names to select” field, type “NT SERVICE\mpssvc”. Then clickCheck Names. The name should change to MpsSvc
  Click OK.
  Select Full Control in the Allow column.
  Click OK.